# Laravel passing array to SOAP call

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, soap

I generate the following Array:

#### EDIT This is the result of the dd($pointsObject);

```
array:1 [▼
  "Points" => array:1 [▼
    "Point" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "Type" => 3
        "Zone" => "Boot"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "Type" => 4
        "Zone" => "Boot"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

To do this SOAP call that I have tested in SoapUI and that works

```
 <Points xsi:type="test:ArrayOfPoint" soapenc:arrayType="test:Point[]" xmlns:test="https://XXXXXXXX.com">
       <Point>
           <Type type="xsd1:DType">1</Type>
           <Zone type="xsd1:Zone">Boot</Zone>
       </Point>
       <Point>
           <Type type="xsd1:DType">1</Type>
           <Zone type="xsd1:Zone">Boot</Zone>
       </Point>
 </DamagePoints>
```

For some reason I get this error in my Laravel application:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'Type' property

Here is my code that generates my Array:

```
$pointsObject = array();

foreach ($points as $point) {
    $pointsObject['Points']['Point'][] = array(
        'Type'  => $point->type_id,
        'Zone'  => $point->zone
    );
}

dd($pointsObject);
```